# URL issues when run restful api war on Tomcat9 in IntelliJ

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ from Eclipse and having issues with the url of my local host rest api.

The situation is that:

1. I have a restful api war file hosted by tomcat 9 in IntelliJ
2. port is 8080
3. war file name is "donriver-telstra-curls-rest.war"
4. request url should have base url of "localhost:8080/donriver-telstra-curls-rest", an full expected example request URL will be: "localhost:8080/donriver-telstra-curls-rest/core/config/system-descriptor"

The issue is that:

1. request url "localhost:8080/donriver-telstra-curls-rest/core/config/system-descriptor" will return 404
2. and instead request url "localhost:8080/core/config/system-descriptor"
   gives 200 with the right response

Actions tried so far:

1. In settings -> tools -> web services, I changed "prefix path web services URL" from "/service" to "/donriver-telstra-curls-rest"
2. In Application Server Edit Configuration -> Server, I changed URL input field from "localhost:8080" to "localhost:8080/donriver-telstra-curls-rest"

Both two above actions did't fix my issue.. Can anyone help?

Updated:

Images attached here:
[url without war file name returns 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCcN9.jpg)
[url with war file name returns 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5HqN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding context path over there it will work with that

**Steps**

1) Go to Run.

2) In that go to Edit configuration.

3) Go to tomcat server.

4) In tomcat server go to deployment.

5)This will open deployment window.

6)In there Go to application context .

7) Insert base URL over there as /donriver-telstra-curls-rest.

8) Click Apply and then ok.

It will run with this localhost:8080/donriver-telstra-curls-rest/core/config/system-descriptor url then

Comment: Thanks Amit, it worked! Just curious, what my actions above do? What url/prefix they change?

Comment: Your project is unable to get the base URL so we just assigned the base URL through context path. Really happy that it worked for you. Try using the following to set your base URL in application.properties file spring.data.rest.base-path=/donriver-telstra-curls-rest/